# If $E$ and $F$ are dense uncountable sets in $\mathbb R$, then $E\cap F$ is dense in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

True or false:

> If $E$ and $F$ are dense uncountable sets in $\mathbb R$, then $E\cap F$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

I believe this is false. Consider two sets. The first being the non-negative rationals together with the negative irrationals. The second being the non-positive rationals together with the positive irrationals. Then each set is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ but their intersection is the singleton $0$.

Please critique my attempt to disprove this statement.

Comment: Hi! Try to ask only one question in a post (unless they are closely related). I have edited out your second question. Please ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is absolutely correct.

Comment: This should be a comment NOT an answer.

Comment: @AnuragA You are basically right. But you will agree that nothing else can be said to answer the question, and writing comments does not make it visible in the list of questions that there is no need for action. If you have a suggestion how to deal with questions of the above type (of which there are many), I will happily act on your suggestion.

Comment: @PaulFrost put it as "community wiki" and nobody will ever complain. Moreover, you can put a more extensive answer by generalizing the OP's answer or provide a different approach. There is always something more to be said :)

Comment: I disagree. This is a perfectly valid answer. OP doesn't ask for more.

Comment: @b00n heT: "*There is always something more to be said*" --- Such as [Partition of the unit interval into uncountably many sets of full outer measure
up vote](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264599/partition-of-the-unit-interval-into-uncountably-many-sets-of-full-outer-measure). (By the way, in this partition "uncountably many" is actually "continuum many".)